# Skype sign in accepting only MS acc

Tags: 8.0, skype

I've had to reset phone to factory defaults and reinstall apps. After that I did not succeed to sign in with my skype account, as it's expecting only MS acc.

WTF is that; did I miss some option? On my Windows Vista and Windows 7 machine I don't have such problems.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype on WP now supports signing-in with a Skype account again as of the 2.25 release.

Answer (score 3):

To sign in to Skype with your existing Skype account, you'll need to link your current Skype account with your Microsoft account. There’s plenty to gain when you sign in to Skype with your Microsoft account:

- one less password to remember
- improved account security
- even easier and more secure password recovery
- access to the Microsoft online services

To link your Skype and Microsoft accounts: [please follow this link](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12184/how-do-i-sign-in-to-skype-for-windows-phone-8)

Comment: But by doing that, the account will be always online, no matter what.

Comment: @LittleHelper that's incorrect, and irrelevant.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen-MSFT Did Microsoft fix that?

Comment: There is a logout option also

Comment: @LittleHelper there's nothing to fix. At any point you're signed in on Skype on WP, you'll be online in the background, so you can receive incoming calls and chat notifications -- it would be kinda counter productive not to. However, you are able to logout, and/or turn the notifications off.

Comment: It got fixed. There was a problem before. Now it's gone. You still don't understand what I was talking about. No reason to shout on me anymore, people.
So, when the Skype and Microsoft account linking procedure was done, it would instantly show you online to everyone even if you didn't even had time to launch a client! When I was logging back in trough my computer, there were always missed calls/texts and when I was asking people why they were trying to reach me when I was offline, they said that I was online and actually all the time. Also simple search will prove that this problem was there.

Comment: Like @ClausJørgensen-MSFT said "At any point you're signed in on Skype on WP, you'll be online in the background ... However, you are able to logout"

Comment: Lol.. Noone is shouting on you, my friend.. Relax :)

Comment: @Vivek Parekh Background? You mean like minimizing the app?

Comment: @LittleHelper The background process runs even when the app is not in use.

Comment: @VivekParekh Yes, I do know that. But I meant even if you were signed out or not connected to the internet, it would still show you online for others. Thank God they fixed it. It was so annoying.